# Change padding to text indent in "Increase indent" TinyMCE

Tags: posts, tinymce, editor, visual-editor

If you click "Increase indent" in the visual editor it adds the following code into the text editor:

```
<p style="padding-left:30px;">
```

How to change it to `text-indent: 30px;` not affecting the core files?

I searched in a lot of files and didn't found any piece of code that would be responsible for that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need to modify the TinyMCE settings object on instantiation:

Reference: [TinyMCE documentation - content formatting](https://www.tinymce.com/docs/configure/content-formatting/#indentation)

WordPress provides a filter for this very purpose called [`tiny_mce_before_init`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/tiny_mce_before_init) which you can use as follows:

```
function modify_tinymce_settings($settings) {

    $settings['indentation'] = '10px';

    return $settings;
}

add_filter('tiny_mce_before_init', 'modify_tinymce_settings');
```

If that does not work precisely, then dump the output of `$settings` in the hook above to see where values for `indentation` are held, they may be nested as part of a multi-dimensional array.

Comment: This gives an idea for a fun day at work, first of April,  with: `if( '4-1' === date( 'n-j' ) ) $settings['indentation'] = rand( 50, 300 ) . 'px';` ;-)

Comment: @birgire hahaha... you have planted the seed, boy am I going to have some pissed clients.

Answer (score 0):

This might guide you in the right direction:

http://codex.wordpress.org/TinyMCE_Custom_Buttons

Specifically the part of adding your own buttons. Since there should be hooks you can probably get away with just modifying the filters tinymce already has.

> ### Adding Custom CSS Styles to MCE Editor
>
> A common use-case for custom TinyMCE plugins is the need for buttons
>   that generate custom styles used in a site's theme, beyond the default
>   HTML tags like Blockquote and Strong. This need is accounted for by
>   the built-in (but hidden in WordPress) 'styleselect' button in TinyMCE
>   and the ability to register custom formats that users can insert using
>   it.
>
> See TinyMCE Custom Styles for information about adding a pulldown menu
>   with custom styles to TinyMCE.
>
> Also see add_editor_style() which is used to register a custom CSS
>   file for TinyMCE that will make the Visual editor display post content
>   the way it will be shown on the frontend of the site.

Comment: Yeah I read that already, but still can't find a file and the piece of code that actually pushes the "padding-left:30px;" to the text editor after selecting a text in visual editor and clicking in TinyMCE Toolbar "Increase/decrease indent".